# Unable to replicate react-table CodeSandbox: API error on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-table, codesandbox

I'm trying to integrate [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-query/tree/master/examples/load-more-infinite-scroll?file=/pages/index.js:0-3057) following CodeSandbox project into my own project. Upon navigating to the `Example` component, however, I'm getting a 404 error: `Error: Request failed with status code 404`. The API is querying the following endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/api/projects?cursor=0`, but that endpoint doesn't return anything.

For completeness, here's code that comprises my component. I excluded the `QueryClientProvider` because it already exists in my `index.js`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useInfiniteQuery } from "react-query";

import useIntersectionObserver from "./hooks/useIntersectionObserver";

export default function Example() {
  const {
    status,
    data,
    error,
    isFetching,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    isFetchingPreviousPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    fetchPreviousPage,
    hasNextPage,
    hasPreviousPage,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(
    "projects",
    async ({ pageParam = 0 }) => {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/projects?cursor=" + pageParam);
      return res.data;
    },
    {
      getPreviousPageParam: (firstPage) => firstPage.previousId ?? false,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage.nextId ?? false,
    }
  );

  const loadMoreButtonRef = React.useRef();

  useIntersectionObserver({
    target: loadMoreButtonRef,
    onIntersect: fetchNextPage,
    enabled: hasNextPage,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Infinite Loading</h1>
      {status === "loading" ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : status === "error" ? (
        <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={() => fetchPreviousPage()}
              disabled={!hasPreviousPage || isFetchingPreviousPage}
            >
              {isFetchingNextPage
                ? "Loading more..."
                : hasNextPage
                ? "Load Older"
                : "Nothing more to load"}
            </button>
          </div>
          {data.pages.map((page) => (
            <React.Fragment key={page.nextId}>
              {page.data.map((project) => (
                <p
                  style={{
                    border: "1px solid gray",
                    borderRadius: "5px",
                    padding: "10rem 1rem",
                    background: `hsla(${project.id * 30}, 60%, 80%, 1)`,
                  }}
                  key={project.id}
                >
                  {project.name}
                </p>
              ))}
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
          <div>
            <button
              ref={loadMoreButtonRef}
              onClick={() => fetchNextPage()}
              disabled={!hasNextPage || isFetchingNextPage}
            >
              {isFetchingNextPage
                ? "Loading more..."
                : hasNextPage
                ? "Load Newer"
                : "Nothing more to load"}
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            {isFetching && !isFetchingNextPage
              ? "Background Updating..."
              : null}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
      <hr />
      <Link href="/about">
        <a>Go to another page</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem likely stems from the `project.js` file, to which I made no changes. Should I be running this endpoint some way in my React app, or should it run automatically with `react-scripts start`? Or is this a problem specific to `next.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you're following is using [nextJS](https://nextjs.org/) which has a built-in HTTP server. Since you're importing `react-router-dom` I'm assuming you're not using Next.

This unfortunately won't work with only `create-react-app` (Which, again, I assume you're using.) You'll either have to move over to NextJS, some other SSR react framework or just spin up a HTTP server on another port that will listen to the API calls you're making.

Comment: yep, I'm using React. I'm not as familiar with `Next` so didn't know it wasn't possible to merge the code. appreciate the clarification